# Unix write to file creating new line only

Tags: bash, unix

I have the following code

```
#!/bin/bash
output= cat $1 | sed s/$2/$3/
if [ -f "$1" ]
then 
    echo $output > "$1"
    echo "Done"
fi
```

Arguments:

1 is file

2 old word

3 new word to replace

File Permission is 777 and for some reason the code will replace the current file with a newline and that's it. Any possible reason for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash
output=`cat $1 | sed s/$2/$3/`
if [ -f "$1" ]
then 
    echo $output > "$1"
    echo "Done"
fi
```

Comment: How come I have to put the quotes? if I echo $output I get the file contents.

Comment: If you put the `` quotes then the commands that are between them are executed.